# Use GC handle to pin down the objects with GC.Collect()

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

**Environment :** .NET4.0, Winform Based Application, Windows 7 (x64), VS2010.

Here is code snippet for Test class which use GC handle to pin down the objects with GC.Collet(). 
I have 2 methods such as "Method1" and "Method2". I want to know which one is correct to use for GC.Collect() while GC handle to pin down objects.

**Code Snippet :**

```
class Test()
{
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory", SetLastError = false)]
            public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint count);

            private GCHandle pinnedArray;
            public GCHandle PinnedArray
            {
                get { lock (this) { return pinnedArray; } }
                set { lock (this) { pinnedArray = value; } }
            }

            IntPtr pointer;
            public IntPtr Pointer
            {
                get { lock (this) { return pointer; } }
                set { lock (this) { pointer = value; } }
            }

            public instance()
            {
                const int size = 1024 * 768;
                byte[] byteArray = null;
                byteArray = new byte[size];

                GCHandle PinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(byteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                IntPtr Pointer = PinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();


            }

            public void Method1(ref IntPtr ImageBuffer )
            {
               try
               {
                unsafe
                {
                    if (ImageBuffer != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        if (Pointer != null)
                        {
                            CopyMemory(Pointer, ImageBuffer, ImageSize);

                            // do stuff
                            // 

                            m_numAcqs++;
                            if (m_numAcqs > _numMaxAcqs)
                            {
                                GC.Collect();
                                m_numAcqs = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }                            
                 }
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  log.AddErrorLog(this.Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, string.Format("Error Occured : MESASGE[{0}]\r\nSOURCE[{1}]\r\nTRACE[{2}]", ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace));
              }

              return;
            }

            public void Method2(ref IntPtr ImageBuffer )
            {
               try
               {
                unsafe
                {
                    if (ImageBuffer != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        if (Pointer != null)
                        {
                            CopyMemory(Pointer, ImageBuffer, ImageSize);

                            // do stuff
                            // 
                         }
                    }                            
                 }

                 m_numAcqs++;
                 if (m_numAcqs > _numMaxAcqs)
                 {
                    GC.Collect();
                    m_numAcqs = 0;
                 }
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  log.AddErrorLog(this.Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, string.Format("Error Occured : MESASGE[{0}]\r\nSOURCE[{1}]\r\nTRACE[{2}]", ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace));
              }

              return;
            }


            public close()
            {
                PinnedArray.free();
            }
    }
```

**EDITED QUESTION :** 
Sorry for unclear question. I attached the real code for my problem. I have System.AccessViolationException error. I have callback method used for handle new images. Here is the code snippet. Marshal.Copy method is recommended. However, If I use this method, System has very slow.

```
// Local callback function used for handle new images
      void HandleImage(ref Jai_FactoryWrapper.ImageInfo ImageInfo)
      {
         // Jai_FactoryWrapper.EFactoryError error = Jai_FactoryWrapper.EFactoryError.Success;

         // This is in fact a callback, so we would need to handle the data as fast as possible and the frame buffer 
         // we get as a parameter will be recycled when we terminate.
         // This leaves us with two choises:
         // 1) Get the work we need to do done ASAP and return
         // 2) Make a copy of the image data and process this afterwards
         //
         // We have the access to the buffer directly via the ImageInfo.ImageBuffer variable
         // 
         // We can access the raw frame buffer bytes if we use "unsafe" code and pointer
         // To do this we need to set the "Allow unsafe code" in the project properties and then access the data like:
         //
         // unsafe
         // {
         //     // Cast IntPtr to pointer to byte
         //     byte* pArray = (byte*)ImageInfo.ImageBuffer;
         //     // Do something with the data
         //     // Read values
         //     byte value = pArray[10];
         //     // Write values
         //     for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
         //         pArray[i] = (byte)(i % 255);
         // }

         // If we want to copy the data instead we can do like this without Unsafe code:
         byte[] array = null;

         if (ImageInfo.ImageBuffer != IntPtr.Zero)
         {
             // Allocate byte array that can contain the copy of data
             array = new byte[ImageInfo.ImageSize];
             IntPtr memoryDest = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)ImageInfo.ImageSize);

             // Do the copying
             Marshal.Copy(ImageInfo.ImageBuffer, array, 0, (int)ImageInfo.ImageSize);
             Marshal.Copy(array, 0, memoryDest , (int)ImageInfo.ImageSize);

             // Do something with the raw data
             CopyToCogBuffer(memoryDest);
         }

         return;
      }

private void CopyToCogBuffer(IntPtr pointer)
{
    try
    {
        ICogImage8RootBuffer CogBuffer = new CogImage8Root();
        CogBuffer.Initialize(int.Parse(myWidthNode.Value.ToString()), int.Parse(myHeightNode.Value.ToString()), pointer, int.Parse(myWidthNode.Value.ToString()), null);
        if (CogBuffer != null)
        {
            CogImage8Grey pImage1 = new CogImage8Grey();
            CogImage8Grey pImage2 = new CogImage8Grey();

            pImage1.SetRoot(CogBuffer);
            pImage2 = pImage1.Copy(CogImageCopyModeConstants.CopyPixels);
            PImage = pImage2;

            _numLiveDisplay++;
            if (_numLiveDisplay > _numMaxLiveDisplay)
            {
                if (_liveProcessing)
                {
                    if (CogDisplay != null)
                        CogDisplay.Image = (CogImage8Grey)pImage2;

                    m_numAcqs++;
                    if (m_numAcqs > _numMaxAcqs)
                    {
                        GC.Collect();
                        m_numAcqs = 0;
                    }
                }

                _numLiveDisplay = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (CogException ex)
    {
        log.AddErrorLog(this.Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, string.Format("Error Occured : MESASGE[{0}]\r\nSOURCE[{1}]\r\nTRACE[{2}]", ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.AddErrorLog(this.Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, string.Format("Error Occured : MESASGE[{0}]\r\nSOURCE[{1}]\r\nTRACE[{2}]", ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace));
    }
}
```

so that I have changed to Pinned down the object. Speed is very fast if I use "CopyMemory" method of Kernel32.dll. However, Randomly "System.AccessViolationException" has occured. I want to know whether the GCHandle PinnedArray is correct use or not.

```
private void HandleImage(ref Jai_FactoryWrapper.ImageInfo ImageInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                if (recipe.CameraInfo[indexID].Use)
                {
                    byte[] byteArray = null;
                    if (ImageInfo.ImageBuffer != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        // Allocate byte array that can contain the copy of data
                        byteArray = new byte[ImageInfo.ImageSize];
                        GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(byteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                        IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
                        CopyMemory(pointer, ImageInfo.ImageBuffer, ImageInfo.ImageSize);
                        CopyToCogBuffer(pointer);
                        pinnedArray.Free();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.AddErrorLog(this.Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, string.Format("Error Occured : MESASGE[{0}]\r\nSOURCE[{1}]\r\nTRACE[{2}]", ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace));
            }

            return;
        }
```

Here is the Call Stack Information from EventViewer.

```
Application Program : ImageDelegateSample.exe 
Framework Version: v4.0.30319 
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException  
Stack :  
at: Cognex.VisionPro.CogImage8Grey.Copy(Cognex.VisionPro.CogImageCopyModeConstants) 
at: ImageDelegateSample.ClientManager.CopyToCogBuffer(IntPtr)  
at: ImageDelegateSample.ClientManager.HandleImage(ImageInfo ByRef)  
at: Jai_FactoryDotNET.CCamera.HandleImage(ImageInfo ByRef)  
at: Jai_FactoryDotNET.CCamera+StreamWork.StreamThread()  
at: System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)  
at: System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)  
at: System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Neither.  You'd at best hope that GC.Collect() does something meaningful if you *release* memory.  Neither method does.  If it needs to go anywhere, very unclear why, then it should go in the close() method.  After setting *byteArray* to null.  This code is dangerous, it makes it far too easy to forget calling close() and leak memory badly.  Which does explain why you think you need to write this code.  It won't fix that problem, the disposable pattern is required.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. However, this code is irrecoverably flawed in *so* many ways, the only real option is to create a new question that clearly states the goal and start over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither.  You'd at best hope that GC.Collect() does something meaningful if you *release* memory.  Neither method does.  If it needs to go anywhere, very unclear why, then it should go in the close() method.  After setting *byteArray* to null.

This code is dangerous, it makes it far too easy to forget calling close() and leak memory badly.  Which does explain why you think you need to write this code.  It won't fix that problem, the disposable pattern is required.  The finalizer can give you the guarantee that you won't forget to unpin the array and the Dispose() method helps you fall in the pit of the *using* statement success.

The CopyMemory() call is very dangerous as well, there is no check that ImageSize <= size and no check on the image format.  1024 * 768 is not enough to store a 1024 x 768 bitmap, a pixel usually requires 3 or 4 bytes.  The heap corruption is very hard to debug.  Always favor Marshal.Copy(), it won't allow corrupting the GC heap.  With the additional advantage that it doesn't require a pinned array.

Comment: Thanks, If I use Marshal.Copy, then Speed is very slow so that I use CopyMemory with PinnedArray. Do you have comment If I use correct or not ?

Comment: If you see Marshal.Copy slower than CopyMemory then you are not using it correctly.  No idea why of course.